# SQL Casting invalid data type

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following tables:

> **EMPLID**=INTEGER, **F_NAME**=VARCHAR, **M_NAME**=VARCHAR,
>   **SALARY_GRADE_ID**=VARCHAR

[image: Employee Table]

> **GRADE_ID**=VARCHAR, **GRADE_AMOUNT**=INTEGER

[image: Salary Table]

My query:

```
SELECT L_Name, Grade_Amount, CAST(AVG(Grade_Amount) AS DECIMAL(0,2)) AS "Total by Last Name" FROM 
Employee INNER JOIN Salary_Grades ON Employee.Salary_Grade_id = Salary_Grades.Grade_Id 
GROUP BY L_Name, Grade_Amount;
```

Is met with the error:

> SQL compilation error: invalid data type specification (2>0)

When I set the decimal specification to (2,2), the query generates the error

> Number out of representable range: type FIXED[SB1]{nullable}, value
>   70000.000000

What is actually happening here? What is wrong with the CAST() statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `decimal` has two components:

- "precision" is the *total* number of decimal places in the number.
- "scale" is the number to right of the decimal point.

With a precision of 0, you are saying no number.

If you only want two digits to the right of the decimal point, use `decimal(2, 2)`.

That seems dangerous to me.  You cannot represent `1.00`, which might be a possible value.  So the most conservation I would use is `decimal(3, 2)` for your specific query.

Based on your error, you probably want at least `decimal(9, 4)`.  But why bother with counting?  Just use something big enough like `(20, 4)`.

Comment: Essentially the 'precision' variable needs to be large enough for the numbers you will be dealing with. In my case, I needed to extend the digits to 9 decimal places. You may want to include that in your answer :)